# Google Form send emails based on answer of checkbox question which allows for multi-option submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form where the answer to a question determines who receives an email upon form submission.  The question is a multi-choice text box, so anywhere from 1 to 6 options can be chosen. The question is the variable `var announce` in the script and all the `if` statements are directed to check for cases of that answer.

My current script works when one option only is chosen (working script = the correct department receives an email).  If two or more options are chosen, no email is sent.  There are no errors showing up in executions.

When multiple options are chosen, the data in the cell reads "Option 1, Option 4".  All my listed cases in the script are for only "Option 1" or "Option 4", etc. Is there a way to make this work without having to make an `if` statement for every possible combination of the 6 choices that could potentially happen?

```
   function sendFormByEmail(e)
{      
  // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address  
  var named_values = e.namedValues  
  var teachername = named_values["Teacher Name"];    
  var info = named_values["Your message/announcement"];  
  var time = named_values["Please include time frame"];  
  var photos = named_values["Include photos with this form if applicable; you can also create the graphic for social media and include below"];  
  var announce = named_values["Choose announcement outlet"];
  var email;
 
 // Optional but change the following variable  
// to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails  
  
// The variable e holds all the form values in an array.  
// Loop through the array and append values to the body.  
var message = "";      
for(var field in e.namedValues) {    
  message += field + ' :: ' 
                + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n"; 
   }   
    
  if(announce.includes("Option 1")){
    var email = "dept1@school.net";
    var subject = "Option 1 request";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
   // put here the case clause, don't include break;
  }
  if(announce.includes("Option 2")){     
    var email = "dept2@school.net";
    var subject = "Option 2 request"; 
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);      
  }   
  if(announce.includes("option 3")) {    
    var email = "dept3@school.net";
    var subject = "Option 3 request";  
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);      
  }
  if(announce.includes("Option 4")) {    
    var email = "dept4@school.net";  
    var subject = "Option 4 request";  
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);     
  }
  if(announce.includes("Option 5")){
    var email = "dept5@school.net";
    var subject = "Option 5 request";
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);   
  }
  if(announce.includes("Option 6")){
    var email = "dept6@school.net";
    var subject = "Option 6 Request";   
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);   
   }
  
    }
```

Console Logs after running tests:
Test 1 - one option chosen on the question that triggers the emails. Email was sent.
*Please note: I entered generic info in script to post - the logs show the actual values.  Example: option 6 is "Phone Call Home"

> Oct 7, 2022, 2:32:21 PM   Debug
> {"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Email
> Address":["heritagecougars@yanceync.net"],"Teacher
> Name":["J"],"Include photos with this form if applicable; you can also
> create the graphic for social media and include below":[""],"Choose
> announcement outlet":["Phone call home"],"Timestamp":["10/7/2022
> 14:32:21"],"Your message/announcement":["test one option
> chosen"],"Please include time frame
> ":[""]},"range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":36,"rowStart":36},"source":{},"triggerUid":"12607666","values":["10/7/2022
> 14:32:21","heritagecougars@yanceync.net","J","Phone call home","test
> one option chosen","",""]}

Test 2 - two options chosen on the question that triggers emails.  No emails sent.

> Oct 7, 2022, 2:32:40 PM   Debug
> {"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Please include time frame
> ":[""],"Teacher Name":["J"],"Your message/announcement":["test 2
> options chosen"],"Email
> Address":["heritagecougars@yanceync.net"],"Timestamp":["10/7/2022
> 14:32:39"],"Include photos with this form if applicable; you can also
> create the graphic for social media and include below":[""],"Choose
> announcement outlet":["MHHS Website, Phone call
> home"]},"range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":37,"rowStart":37},"source":{},"triggerUid":"12607666","values":["10/7/2022
> 14:32:39","heritagecougars@yanceync.net","J","MHHS Website, Phone call
> home","test 2 options chosen","",""]}

Comment: Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` after `function sendFormByEmail(e)
{  `, make a new test form submission and add the execution logs to the question. P.S. it's very likely that the values on announce doesn't match any of the strings used as parameters of the `announce.includes` expressions.

Comment: @Rubén, they match when one option is chosen and I think that is where my issues come into play.  When more than one option is chosen and I need multiple people emailed based on the different options, then the listed expressions don't match anymore. I'm hoping for a solution other than listing every potential combination.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms is sending the options checked as a string:

```
"Choose announcement outlet":["MHHS Website, Phone call home"]
```

Considering this, replace

```
var announce = named_values["Choose announcement outlet"];
```

by

```
var announce = named_values["Choose announcement outlet"][0].split(',');
```

Notes:

1. Assure that the options in corresponding question in your Google Forms doesn't include commas.
2. The parameters of `announce.includes` should be the value of one of the options in the Google Forms, i.e. instead of `"Option 6"` it should be `"Phone call home"`.

Comment: Some progress: when multiple options chosen, an email is now sent, but it only sends to the first listed option.  For example, if option 2 and option 5 are chosen, the email goes to option 2 only.